# Jquery image and caption swap by clicking thumbnails

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide

I am trying to create a simple jquery image gallery, where clicking a thumbnail button (1 per image) swaps the image by means of a fade and swaps the text caption.

I have divs containing the images absolutely positioned one on top of the other, and a caption next to it, with thumbnails/buttons underneath.

The jquery I have written works - apart from on the first transition when the page is loaded. The first transition makes the target image appear, then fade out, then fade back in. It should simply fade in.

I'm new to jquery so apologies if this is poor code...

Can anyone tell me why the first transition doesn't work correctly?

Thanks

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery_button').click(function(){
     $('.gallery_slide').animate( {opacity:0.0}, 2000 );
     $('#slide'+$(this).attr('id')).toggleClass('visible');
     $('#slide'+$(this).attr('id')).animate( {opacity:1.0}, 2000 );
     $('.gallery_caption').hide();
         $('#caption'+$(this).attr('id')).show();
         $('#caption'+$(this).attr('id')).toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery_slider">
<div class="gallery_slide" id="slide1"><img src="img1.jpg"/></div>
<div class="gallery_slide hidden" id="slide2"><img src="img2.jpg"/></div>
<div class="gallery_slide hidden" id="slide3"><img src="img3.jpg"/></div>

<div class="gallery_caption" id="caption1">Caption 1</div>
<div class="gallery_caption hidden" id="caption2"/>Caption2</div>
<div class="gallery_caption hidden" id="caption3"/>Caption3</div>

<div class="gallery_button"><img src="button.gif" id="1"/></div>
<div class="gallery_button"><img src="button.gif" id="2"/></div>
<div class="gallery_button"><img src="button.gif" id="3"/></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery_slider{position:relative; height:500px;}
.gallery_slide{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:640px; height:480px;}
.gallery_caption{position:absolute; bottom:20px; left:660px; width:160px; min-height:150px;}
.gallery_button{width:10px; height:10px; margin:490px 8px 0 0; float:left;}

.hidden{display:none;}
.visible{display:block; visibility:visible;}
```

Comment: `id="1"`. ID's can't start with numbers and must be unique.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/znsS5/ and I fixed the identical button IDs... It seems to be working when you click, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Thanks for that - mistake on my part, id's in fact unique in the actual code. @j08691 I belive HTML5 allows for id's to start with numbers now

Comment: Yes they do. However for compatibility I'd recommend avoiding starting IDs with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what this code is telling it to do:

```
 $('#slide'+$(this).attr('id')).toggleClass('visible'); // shows it
 $('#slide'+$(this).attr('id')).animate( {opacity:1.0}, 2000 );  // fades it in
```

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.gallery_button img').click(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    $('.gallery_caption').hide();
    $('.gallery_slide').fadeOut(2000, function () {
      $('#caption' + id).show();
      $('#slide' + id).fadeIn(2000);
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Utb8f/

Comment: Thanks very much - that's spot on and fixes the problem, though now the original image/div fades out, then the target image/div appears with no fade in. Is there a way to make it fade in?

Comment: Updated answer. using `fadeToggle` should be the quickest fix.

Comment: Thanks @blazemonger that helps, but doesn't quite work - it makes the fades work when going clicking the buttons in sequence 1 - 2 - 3, but when going backward i.e. clicking 2 when on 3, the image does not fade out, though the caption does swap

Comment: That now works perfectly, thank you - except... after the fade out and fade in completes, the new slide fades in and out once more
It doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but I wanted to point out that your HTML could do with a bit of review.

Your buttons at the bottom are nested, since the divs don't seem to have an end . Also, some of your other divs are of the format

```
<div />something</div>
```

instead of

```
<div>something</div>
```

Here's a cleaned up version of your code:

```
<div id="gallery_slider">
<div class="gallery_slide" id="slide1"><img src="img1.jpg"/></div>
<div class="gallery_slide hidden" id="slide2"><img src="img2.jpg"/></div>
<div class="gallery_slide hidden" id="slide3"><img src="img3.jpg"/></div>

<div class="gallery_caption" id="caption1">Caption 1</div>
<div class="gallery_caption hidden" id="caption2">Caption2</div>
<div class="gallery_caption hidden" id="caption3">Caption3</div>

<div class="gallery_button"><img src="button.gif" id="1"/></div>
<div class="gallery_button"><img src="button.gif" id="1"/></div>
<div class="gallery_button"><img src="button.gif" id="1"/></div>
</div>
```

Also, if you want to look at some existing stuff (it's always good to use something that's out there and has been tested by loads of people if you're up for it) or just to get an idea of how other people have done this before, I've gone through and found some popular plugins that I think achieve what you're trying to achieve:

- http://www.tn3gallery.com/?refCode=ae1bfc
- http://www.pikachoose.com/
- http://www.robertnyman.com/picture-slides/
- http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/
- http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/#ad-image-0
- http://www.queness.com/post/3036/create-a-custom-jquery-image-gallery-with-jcarousel
- http://slidesjs.com/
- http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
- http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/

Hope that helps.

**Edit:**

I've gone through and made a little code snippet (humour me with the cats) to exemplify how you could do this, without using IDs, so you can add new elements and swap them around without having to worry about IDs.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6agB/1/ (after second edit)
http://jsfiddle.net/Q6agB/3/ (third edit, with comments)

It's good to keep elements which correlate (so images with captions) together, so you can move them around easily and, when someone glances at your stuff (it could be you in a while, after you've forgotten all about your code), they can easily tell what you've been doing. So that's why I grouped the captions with the images.

Is that what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the original post now - copying and pasting from the working example in a hurry lead to missing off the closing divs.
Thanks for the links - I'll check those out. Wanted to try and do it from scratch as a first go at jquery - but will see how these guys have done it too

Comment: P.S.: you're seeing the same image of a cat twice. It is working. :)

Comment: Thank you for the jsfiddle - not quite what I'm after though - each button needs to show a corresponding image, where as in the example here you can click the button for a second time and a different image appears

Comment: Sorry. I wrote the jQuery.inArray() function from memory and, therefore, wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/Q6agB/1/

Comment: Now that works perfick :) Thank you.
I'm not sure quite what all the jquery means yet so am trying to work my head round it. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for the comments - it now makes sense, enjoying finding my feet in jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

I was keen to work out how to sort the original problem using the original format as this was my first piece of jquery, so I finally managed to get it to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.gallery_button').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $('.gallery_caption:visible').hide();
    $('.gallery_slide:visible').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $('#slide' + id).fadeIn(5000);
        $('#caption' + id).show();
    });
    });
});
```

Thanks all for the input and help